# SQL - Using the results of subquery in SELECT in the SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:

```
SELECT
    (
        ...
    ) AS imageName,
    (
        ...
    ) AS imageURL,
    CONCAT(imageName, ' ', imageURL)
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all inside the CONCAT, like this:

```
select CONCAT(( select ... ), ' ', ( select ... ))
```

Comment: The OP needs to select the values `imageName` and `imageURL` as well besides the concatenated string.

Comment: Both work. I used this way because I do not need the separate values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following but watch out the tables' aliases:

```
   SELECT
     T.imageName, T.imageURL
     CONCAT(imageName, ' ', imageURL)
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT
      (
        ...
       ) AS imageName,
       (
        ...
      ) AS imageURL
       FROM ... AS innerT
   ) T
```